# Using bnlearn Function "cpquery" Within a Loop

Tags: r, probability, bayesian-networks

I'm attempting to use the [bnlearn](http://www.bnlearn.com) [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnlearn/index.html) to calculate conditional probabilities, and I'm running into a problem when the ["cpquery"](http://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/cpquery.html) function is used within a loop. I've created an example, shown below, using data included with the package. When using the cpquery function in a loop, a variable created in the loop ("evi" in the example) is not recognized by the function. I receive the error:

```
Error in parse(text = evi) : object 'evi' not found
```

The creation steps of "evi" are based on examples provided by the author.

Any help you could provide would be great. I'm desperate to find a way that I can apply the cpquery function for a large number of observations.

```
library(bnlearn)
data(learning.test)
fitted = bn.fit(hc(learning.test), learning.test)

bn.function <- function(network, evidence_data) {
  a <- NULL
  b <- nrow(evidence_data)
  for (i in 1:b) {
    evi <- paste("(", names(evidence_data), "=='",
               sapply(evidence_data[i,], as.character), "')",
               sep = "", collapse = " & ")
    a[i] <- cpquery(network, (C=='c'), eval(parse(text=evi)))
  }
  return(a)
}

test <- bn.function(fitted, learning.test)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been in contact with the author of the bnlearn package, and it appears the error I am receiving is due to a scoping problem with the cpquery function. This is evident when I'm able to get the cpquery function to work properly in a for-loop that is constructed _outside_ of a user-defined function, but have the error when the same for-loop is used _inside_ of a user-defined function.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with cpquery in loops and a quick workaround that worked for me was to include a line `evi <<- evi` before the cpquery call. This defines the variable in the global environment.

Comment: I guess your problem was solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676501/r-bnlearn-eval-inside-function

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the scoping problem, you can postpone the call to `eval` and do it *inside* the `cpquery` function. If you directly pass `evi` (the character variable) to `cpquery` and then parse it inside the definition, the chain of environments gets *shifted* and `cpquery` will have access to `evi`.

You can use `m.cpquery <- edit(cpquery)` to fork your own version of the function and insert the following line at its beginning:

```
evidence = parse(text = evidence)
```

and then save your new function.

So the heading of `m.cpquery` will look like:

```
> m.cpquery
function (fitted, event, evidence, cluster = NULL, method = "ls", 
    ..., debug = FALSE) 
{
    evidence = parse(text = evidence)
    check.fit(fitted)
    check.logical(debug)
...
```

Now you can use `m.cpquery` in your own function like before, except we'll pass the plain character variable to it:

```
a[i] <- m.cpquery(network, (C=='c'), evi)
```

Note that in the first line of `m.cpquery`, we only parsed the evidence character variable and didn't call `eval` on it. `cpquery` is a front-end to `conditional.probability.query` (see [here](https://github.com/cran/bnlearn/blob/master/R/frontend-simulation.R)) and we're relying on `conditional.probability.query`'s subsequent call to `eval`.

I should say that this is a rather ugly workaround. And it only works if you are using *logic sampling* (`method='ls'`). But if you want to use *likelihood weighting*, the `check.mutilated.evidence` function will raise an error. I haven't checked if injecting an `eval` expression before it gets called would result in a mayhem of subsequent errors leading to hell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is due to a bugfix or just because I tried another approach - anyways, looping works if you iteratively build up the evidence list outside of the cpquery-function.

An example for an iteration through a list called evidenceData with all-positive evidences:

```
for(i in names(evidenceData)){
  loopEvidenceList <- list()
  loopEvidenceList[[i]] <- "TRUE"
  a =cpquery(fitted = bayesNet, event = queryNode == "TRUE", 
             evidence = loopEvidenceList, method = "lw", n = 100000)
  print(a)
  }
```

Depending on the way your evidence is availible, you might need more sophisticated preparation of the "loopEvidenceList" but once you got that prepared, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the problem is you are using the same variable in evidence as well as event. Learning.test contains the values of "C" variable. then we are trying to predict C as the event. Maybe using a subset of the original dataset excluding C will do the trick

Comment: Could you provide sample code of for how that would work?