# Why I'm receiving "Object" not found within this function?

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing, bnlearn

```
query_averager <- function(arg1,
                           arg2) {
n = tibble()
   i = 1
   while (i <= 100) {
   n[i] <- cpquery(fitted = fitted_bn_01,
        event = (ret == "Acima da Selic") ,
        evidence = (solidez == arg1) & (resultado == arg2))
   i = i+1

   }
return (mean(n))
}

Query_result <- query_averager(arg1 = "1", arg2 = "Lucro acima da mediana")
```

This gives me "object arg1 not found", but when I use the function `cpquery()` outside, it works perfectly.

Working code without the query_averager function:

```
cpquery(fitted = fitted_bn_01,
    event = (ret == "Acima da Selic") ,
    evidence = (solidez == "1") & (resultado == "Lucro acima da median"))
```

I believe it doesn't matter what the other variables are, the main problem is why:

```
 solidez == "1"
```

works and the code snippet below doesn't:

```
solidez == arg1
```

Comment: Where does the function `cpquery` come from? Does it use lazy evaluation? are you using variables when you use `cpquery` outside the function or are you putting in literal values?

Comment: Where are `ret`, `solidez`, `resultado`, `fitted_bn_01` defined? If you tag this with [tag:functional-programming], is it just irony that the scope breach suggested here defies some tenets of it, or is there something else going on here?

Comment: The cpquery is a function from the bnlearn package; I will edit the main post with the working code that I described. I don't know if it uses lazy evaluation or not. // I don't know  if the functional-programming tag is correct or not. May just be a newbie mistake, if so, please forgive me xD

Comment: @YBS Same problem. I've tried passing as argument "1" and 1, the output didn't change.

Comment: @MrFlick Now I know what Lazy Evaluation is, and yes it is lazy evaluated.

Comment: Answer by @Marco Sandri should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676501/r-bnlearn-eval-inside-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't have any variables in the evidence expression because they will not be evaluated in the function body. So it seems you have to manipulate the function call prior to evaluation. I don't have this package installed and working, but it seems like this would work:

```
query_averager <- function(arg1, arg2) {
   n = tibble()
   i = 1
   while (i <= 100) {
   n[i] <- eval(substitute(cpquery(fitted = fitted_bn_01,
        event = (ret == "Acima da Selic") ,
        evidence = (solidez == arg1) & (resultado == arg2))))
   i = i+1

   }
  mean(n)
}
```

The `substitute()` part injects the values of `arg1` and `arg2` into the expression. Then we evaluate that expression with `eval()`.

Comment: Perfect answer, do you know what any reference that I could study this kind of problem? The solution is perfect but I don't understand why. 

Also, I've found that the generic {predict()} function has the {method = "bayes-lw" , n = 100} that it's equivalent to the cpquery.

Comment: Most functions don't work this way so it's a bit unusual so sometimes you just have to guess if the function isn't well documented. If you haven't read the "metaprograming" section of "Advanced R" that might be a good place to get started. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html But there's nothing in there that would probably directly address this particular issue.